# Project broken by unidentified subdependency: how to recover? How to `npm install` with all packages limited by a date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, npm, npm-install

My project is successfully deployed via CI and working fine. But when I build it from the same commit locally, the project freezes without any error message. It's a huge Ember app with an enormous pipeline, and I've exhausted all my debugging ideas.

My only guess so far is that an npm subdependency update has broken something. I don't know which package is to blame. :(

I have no `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. I tried to introduce shrinkwrapping to the team, but it was causing too much trouble, so we went back to not using it.

No other team member has an up to date version of the project locally, so I don't have anyone to ask for a fresh `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

I know the date at which the project was building correctly.

**How do I tell npm to install every package (including subdependencies) limited by a date (in addition to restrictions specified in `package.json` files)?**

If I were able to do that, I could see if the project starts working again. If it does, I could shrinkwrap and identify the troublesome package.

Any other suggestions to recover from this failure are also very welcome.

PS I'm using NVM, so I've tried both npm v2 and v3 -- same result.

Comment: Look through the git history of package.json and you can see what the recent changes are.

Comment: Have you tried node-inspector? You can place a breakpoint in your ember-cli-build file and then run commands like ember build from there. Let me know if you're interested in this approach and I can dig up the specific commands and steps I used to debug a similar problem